# OpenDKIM record DNS query works only sometimes, seemingly randomly

Tags: domain-name-system, email, dkim

My server is modalduality.org and I have a DKIM record at 201703._domainkey.modalduality.org.

When I run

`dig 201703._domainkey.modalduality.org TXT`

I get back the correct record in the ANSWER SECTION sometimes, but other times I only get an NXDOMAIN error, the AUTHORITY SECTION, no ANSWER SECTION, and I don't get the DKIM  record as a result. If I run it ten times in a row maybe half will show the correct result. What could be causing this behavior? I'm using Namecheap to set my DNS, cname for the dkim key points to a Cloudns subdomain.

Comment: when did you create this dns entry? could the old answer (NXDOMAIN) be cached in some of your dns resolvers or even on the authoritative DNS servers?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize it was possible for me to be querying different resolvers each time - I created this only 15-20 minutes ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you get results from different NS servers or local cache.
First, try to specify NS server you want to query, as far 'dig' it will be:

```
dig mydomain.org @ns1.mydomain.org
```

and check if it returns correct value each time you query it.
I suppose it solves your problem.

Comment: Yes, I think the issue was I was querying different paths and some of them were old. Seems to work fine now, thanks.